# OpenCV Android App Stops without Error Message

Tags: android, opencv

I've developed an app to track a colored ball, using the OpenCV-Library and its Java-Wrappers.
After a few minutes, my app closes without any error message.
Neither the logcat nor the Debugger have shown any relevant messages to me.
Also, the occurence of each close seems to be random.

After analyzing the memory usage of my app, I've discovered that the method MatOfPoint.toArray() produces roughly 97 percent of the data.
But if my app runs out of memory, there has to be a error message.
Is it possible to avoid this method?

This is the only method that is executed each frame.

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.resize(mRgba, mRgbaF, mRgbaF.size(), 0, 0, 0);
    Core.flip(mRgbaF, mRgba, -1);

    if(mRgba.channels()>1)
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, smHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);
    else smHsv = mRgba;

    Core.inRange(smHsv, mLowerBound, mUpperBound, mMask);

    contours.clear();
    Imgproc.findContours(mMask.clone(), contours, mHistory, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    if(contours.size() > 0){
        MatOfPoint largestContour = new MatOfPoint();
        double max = 0;
        for(MatOfPoint m: contours){
            double tmp = Imgproc.contourArea(m);
            if(tmp > max) {
                max = tmp;
                largestContour = m;
            }
        }

        points = largestContour.toArray();

        Point center = new Point();
        float[] radius = new float[1];
        if(!largestContour.empty()) {
            Imgproc.minEnclosingCircle(new MatOfPoint2f(points), center, radius);
        }

   return mRgba;    
}
```

Is there anything I've missed or is there a way of getting ALL error messages of my system?
What am I doing wrong?

Complete code can be found here:
[BallTracker Activity](http://pastebin.com/snYkvdVB)